# .NET 6 upgrade issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am getting build issues while adding `Net6` to the target frameworks in a `.csproj` file.

In my project repo, I have many .NET projects. Folder structure looks something like this:

```
Repo Folder
            + Project-1
            + Project-2
            + Project-3
            + Project-4
            + .........
            + global.json
```

In the repo there is one `global.json` file in which the .NET Core SDK version is mentioned.

`global.json` looks like this:

```
{   
    "sdk": 
    {     
        "version": "3.1.100",     
        "rollForward": "latestFeature"   
    } 
}
```

Build error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuKyP.png)

Root cause: In the `global.json` file we have specified SDK version 3.1.100 which is not part of .NET 6.

To get rid of this issue, I have created a new `global.json` file with a .NET 6 SDK version, which solved the issue in Visual Studio.

However, unfortunately, when I build the all projects from PowerShell, it is still picking up the SDK version from the parent json file (.NET Core 3.1).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgGX8.png)

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2022 installed?

Comment: in the powershell window that is failing, if you type `dotnet --info`, is there an entry (near the end) that says "global.json file:" ? and if you look at the file it points to: does that file have the correct version?

Comment: also, you said you made a *new* global.json file - did you not just update the existing one?

Comment: Your target framework is probably specified as `net60` but it needs to be `net6.0`. Notice the dot in the correct one. TFMs for .NET Core and .NET 5+ have the dot in them to prevent ambiguity once version 10 is reached, whereas .NET Framework ones do not (e.g. net462).

Comment: Please show your .csproj file to confirm.

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net35;netstandard2.0;net6</TargetFrameworks>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1603</NoWarn>
    <Company>Phreesia</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © Phreesia 2021</Copyright>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</ Project>

Comment: I was close...  you have `net6`.  Because it doesn't have a dot in it, The TFM parser sees it as `.NETFramework` instead of `.NETCoreApp`. It needs to be `net6.0`.

Comment: Also, don't add details in the comments. [Edit] the question to add details.